# How to use "v-if" and "v-else" in same tag in HTML using Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I use Vue js conditional statements in multiple elements.

In some cases, i need to place if and else in same element to filter the elements.

Here,i use multiple elements to apply if and else.

```
   <block v-if="nb == 3" align="left"></block>
   <block v-if="nb > 3" align="center"></block>
```

But i want to apply both in single element like,

```
  <block v-if="nb == 3" align="left" v-else align="center"></block>
```

Is it possible ?

Or Any other solution to apply this ?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Rather than using `v-if`, try binding the attribute to a ternary expression.

```
// : is a shorthand for v-bind:
<block :align="nb == 3 ? 'left' : 'center'"></block>
```

If that looks a little too messy for you (or if the logic you want to use is too complicated to express in a single line), you could also try creating a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) in your component that returns `"left"` or `"center"`, and then bind to that instead.

Comment: So Computed property is better than this "if and else"...?

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan: I'd use a ternary expression for something this simple, but anything more would be much more readable put into a computed property. It's a stylistic choice though, do what feels right.

Comment: @ShankarThiyagaraajan: As far as I know, there's no way of using `v-if` and `v-else` on the same element, so I think binding to something is the only way.

Comment: `v-if` and `v-else` is for an entire element and not for an attribute, so this ternary seems like the bast way.

Comment: @StevenWade: I agree - while you could duplicate the element and use `v-if/else`, it'd make your markup more cluttered than it needs to be.

Comment: Nice answer. is there any options if the actual tag content?

Answer (score 7):

You can't use `v-if` and `v-else` on the same element.

I'd personally use a computed property.

I'm assuming your `nb` is a reactive variable or similar.

Therefore you should be looking for something like this:

```
<block v-bind:align="computedAlign"></block>
```

and then in your component

```
// assuming you're using data and not props
data() {
  return {
    nb: 1 // default
  }
},
// some other stuff that sets the nb variable in some way
computed: {
  computedAlign() => {
    if (this.nb === 3) {
      return 'left'
    } else {
      return 'center'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply achieve that with a ternary operator

```
<block :align="nb==3?'right':'left'"></block>
```

Comment: already exist as an answer